# How to to create another array for sumproduct that gives 1 for a cell that contain certain word or 0 if not

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum the total machine work but sometime the machine work at 2 different job at the same time. I want to make everytime the machine countif(statement,"*side by side*") the minute divided by 2 before being sum.

Edit:

- I accidently put B12 on formula not B2.
- Added column H
- Lost time G2
  =IF(WEEKDAY(B2,11)<6,420,300)-SUMPRODUCT(($D:$D),--($A:$A=A2),--($B:$B=B2))+SUMPRODUCT(($D:$D),--($A:$A=A2),--($B:$B=B2),($H:$H))/2

I don't want the column H if possible. So how to create some sort of array that gives 1 for everytime there is side by side statement

[book1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jqht.png)/RytH8.png

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you tried? F.e. Add one additional column that applies the condition if the machine is working in one task...'=IF(C2="side by side",D2,D2/2)' ?

Comment: Sorry, do you mean like the column H? I just edited the question. So if it is possible is there someway to create column H into sumproduct formula without adding additional column.